# Politics (science, sociology, theory of) questions should go where?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, politics

I understand the need to prevent there being a place for what generally passes for political "thought" on the interwebz, but where can questions regarding political science, theory of politics, political sociology and the sociology of politics be asked?

Questions would need to be strictly limited (i.e. moderated) to well-established and well-defined well-focused academic questions and unambiguous factual questions.

Examples would include things such as

1. What is the median voter theorem and how can it explain multi-partite systems?
2. What does the double-majority requirements for certain legislation in the EU mean?
3. What did Weber define as class?
4. How does rational choice theory explain the existence of voting?
5. Under the german basic law, what powers does the supreme court have?
6. What is the Nato Security Council?

Essay-type broader questions would be discouraged. This is not a discussion forum after all.

Comment: Are you aware of http://area51.stackexchange.com/? More specifically, the [Politics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906/politics) proposal?

Comment: Check out [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) for a proposal that fits your requirements. There's no live site where these questions would be on topic.

Comment: Interesting sample questions.  Of course, IRL, the questions of such a site would be more like "What mental defects cause people to vote for the XXXX party?"

Comment: Those don't go on programmers.SE??  ;)

Comment: Thanks to all who pointed me to that Area51 bit. I am new to StackExchange and hadn't hunted that section down yet. But yes, @ಠ_ಠ Won't♦, I appreciate most questions would probably be about contemporary 'politics'.

Comment: @Adam Rackis , whoops, I thought this was meta for Stack exchange, not Stack Overflow. Apologies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything you are looking for is in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), as stated in the comments. There is also the [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sociology) Stack Exchange (currently in beta).

On Area 51:
[Politics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906/politics): "Proposed Q&A site for objective discussion and questions about governments, policies and political processes."

Comment: thanks, though I am sceptical that a site for private investigators is categorised with electoral theory :)

Comment: http://politics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7):

The best place would be the as-of-yet unlaunched [Politics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906), currently in the commitment phase. Join it, and help it launch before the election season, no doubt it would be quite interesting. Good luck.